# Tracking files in Git that are added by reference to project in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, git

I have a few iOS projects that all use the same intro videos.  The video files are not in any of the project folders.  When I add them by reference to the Xcode projects, I can't track (add?) them with Git.  Does the file need to be local to the project folder to add them to a repo, or is there a way to do this?  I add them by reference so I can make changes to the one video and have it reflect in all the projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for situations like this, where i share code amongst projects, i create a git submodule that contains the common code, where the git submodule is basically a mini-clone of a git repository of that common code.

thus, for source that is shared, i can play with it in the submodule of one project without affecting the other projects until i'm happy with it and commit and push it to the submodule's origin/master, and merge it from there to the other projects.  the same should be possible for binary as well.

this way, the tracking does show up in Xcode for me.